# Is it possible to have Multi-line DataGridView cells without wrapping text?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I know I can set `WrapMode` to true on the `DefaultCellStyle` of the `RowTemplate`, however this doesn't give me the behaviour I want. I am displaying a list of strings within each cell, and I therefore want the carriage returns to be recognised, but I don't want text from long items wrapping.

Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I need the same too. Unfortunately, enabling wrapping also removes the "..." bit which shows there's more text to see. There has to be a way around this - I'll open up a bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:
[image: Screen shot]

I used two events:

1. I've measured the height after a cell edit.
2. I've measured text when painting cell, and trimmed it if needed, and repeat till it fits.

Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly int _rowMargins;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int rowHeight = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height;
        _rowMargins = rowHeight - dataGridView1.Font.Height;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView view = sender as DataGridView;
        DataGridViewCell cell = view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        string text = string.Format("{0}", cell.FormattedValue);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, view.Font);
            view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height = Math.Max(size.Height + _rowMargins, view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height);
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 || e.RowIndex == -1)
        {
            return;
        }
        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All ^ DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);

        DataGridView view = sender as DataGridView;

        string textToDisplay = TrimTextToFit(string.Format("{0}", e.FormattedValue), (int) (e.CellBounds.Width * 0.96), view.Font);

        bool selected = view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected;
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(selected ? e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor : e.CellStyle.ForeColor);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(textToDisplay, view.Font, brush, e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y + _rowMargins / 2);

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private static string TrimTextToFit(string text, int contentWidth, Font font)
    {
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font);

        if (size.Width < contentWidth)
        {
            return text;
        }

        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (i < text.Length)
        {
            sb.Append(text[i++]);
            size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(sb.ToString(), font);

            if (size.Width <= contentWidth) continue;

            sb.Append("...");

            while (sb.Length > 3 && size.Width > contentWidth)
            {
                sb.Remove(sb.Length - 4, 1);
                size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(sb.ToString(), font);
            }

            while (i < text.Length && text[i] != Environment.NewLine[0])
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
```

Enjoy,
Ofir

### Designer code:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.LineNumber = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.Content = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.LineNumber,
        this.Content});
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 55;
        this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(493, 237);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);
        this.dataGridView1.CellPainting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellPainting);
        // 
        // LineNumber
        // 
        this.LineNumber.FillWeight = 30F;
        this.LineNumber.Frozen = true;
        this.LineNumber.HeaderText = "#";
        this.LineNumber.MaxInputLength = 3;
        this.LineNumber.Name = "LineNumber";
        this.LineNumber.ReadOnly = true;
        this.LineNumber.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
        this.LineNumber.Width = 30;
        // 
        // Content
        // 
        this.Content.HeaderText = "Content";
        this.Content.Name = "Content";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(518, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Is it possible to have Multi-line DataGridView cells without wrapping text?";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn LineNumber;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Content;
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me currently. Do I set WrapMode to true or false? I'll try and edit the question (even though it's not my own) and paste the code I currently have so far. By the way, I intend to create the table dynamically and set the cell contents via code (rather than from the user), though both would presumably be handy for others. The bounty runs out very soon now, but I'll open it up again to encourage potentially good answers like yours.

Comment: Hi *Dan W*,  
Use WrapMode = False.

Comment: Hi *Dan W*,  

This is of course a demo only, I filled the first column with line number, and replaced the '.' with *Enter* to make it easier for me.

On *dataGridView1_CellEndEdit* all is needed is to measure the text.

Regards,
Ofir

Comment: Aha! I discovered - it seems to be working great for the second column, just not the first or others. Can you adjust the code so that they work too?

Comment: I've put the code I have so far here: http://www.skytopia.com/stuff/table-code.txt

Comment: AHA!! I've tried disabling the line `if (e.ColumnIndex != 1 || e.RowIndex == -1) return;` from your code, and all the columns are great. Can you remove that bit of code and then I think a bounty is coming your way :)

Comment: Just found a small bug in the last row if you set AllowUserToAddRows to false, and then try resizing that row. As you can see, the text is going below the white table cell and into the grey area. See: http://www.skytopia.com/stuff/small-table-bug.jpg

Comment: See below, I add an static class to make it happen: *MultilineTriming*

Comment: That's great - thank you. Perhaps you can consolidate the MultilineTriming class into this answer. Feel free to remove the Designer stuff too, though that's up to you. Thanks so much for the answer - it looks like quite a lot of effort went into it, and certainly deserves the bounty and to be voted to the top!

Answer (score 2):

i test this code and result is very good test this please :

Note :  create a form and Datagrid on , set following datagrid Properties

1- AutoSizeRowsMode to AllCells.
  2- WrapMode for Target Column to True

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DGMultiLine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int max = 12; //min Column Width in Char
            //do this for all rows of column for max Line Size in values

            string str = "Hello\r\nI am mojtaba\r\ni like programming very very \r\nrun this code and  pay attention to result\r\n Datagrid Must show this Line Good are you see whole of this Thats Finished!";
            string[] ss = str.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //find max Line Size To Now
            for (int i = 0; i < ss.Length; i++)
                if (ss[i] != null && ss[i] != "")
                    if (ss[i].Length > max)
                        max = ss[i].Length;
            //Set target Column Width
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = max*5;//for adequate value you must refer to screen resolution
            //filling datagrigView for all values
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = str;
        }

    }
}
```

you can add a hidden Column by real fullText and a visible Column that show string value by above code but in string lines size that exceed from your Max Column Size clip string and add ... to end . ( if it isn't clear ask to write full code )

Comment: Hi thanks, but it looks as though that's for fixed-width fonts only. Also, the columns may be resized by the user at some stage, and even if there was code for that, I would be worried that may slow down very big tables...

Comment: Just to also add - I'd want the column widths to stay at a constant small value, since some cells may otherwise contain VERY long lines of text. So if the line went past the cell width, a "..." would show.

Answer (score 1):

It has worked for me by doing \r\n together with the string.

For example "Hello" + \r\n. It then goes to the next row.

EDIT:

Just saw that this was WinForms. The trick above only works in WPF.

EDIT2:

You can use:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

And if you don't want long items wrapping, you just do:

```
String stringTest = "1234567891";
if (stringTest.Length > 8)
{
   stringTest = stringTest.Replace(stringTest.Substring(8), "...");
}
```

This will add "..." if the String is longer then 8.

Comment: Tried it - doesn't work for me. I used the code `dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "Hello and welcome to" + "\r\n" + "Earth";`. Make sure to turn WrapMode off for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the new info. I didn't make it clear, but really, I was hoping for variable-width font support (for better international support), and the user may adjust the columns which could be slow for very big tables.

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can just put some of words visible and then the Full Text can be shown in Tooltip on mouse over that cell.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to do this without setting WrapMode to true.  However, you should be able to "trick" the DataGridView into doing this by setting the width of the cell to be wide enough to display all items on a single line.

[Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5801/Adjust-combo-box-drop-down-list-width-to-longest-s) an example of this being done with a ComboBo.

Comment: Thanks, though I was hoping for smaller cell widths to allow data to be shown more compactly, and also due to potential lines which may be extremely long.

Answer (score 0):

This class get the `DataGridView` instance and add the behavior for trimming multi line elipsis (...) for width and height as well.

Usage:

```
MultilineTriming.Init(ref dataGridView); // that's it!
```

Enjoy,

```
public static class MultilineTriming
{
    private static int _rowMargins;

    public static void Init(ref DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
        dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;

        _rowMargins = dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height - dataGridView.Font.Height;

        Unregister(dataGridView);

        dataGridView.CellEndEdit += DataGridViewOnCellEndEdit;
        dataGridView.CellPainting += DataGridViewOnCellPainting;
        dataGridView.RowsAdded += DataGridViewOnRowsAdded;
        dataGridView.Disposed += DataGridViewOnDisposed;
    }

    private static void DataGridViewOnRowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView view = sender as DataGridView;
        DataGridViewRow row = view.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.FormattedValue == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText((string)cell.FormattedValue, view.Font);
            row.Height = Math.Max(size.Height + _rowMargins, row.Height);
        }
    }

    private static void DataGridViewOnDisposed(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
        Unregister(dataGridView);

    }

    public static void Unregister(DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        dataGridView.RowsAdded -= DataGridViewOnRowsAdded;
        dataGridView.CellEndEdit -= DataGridViewOnCellEndEdit;
        dataGridView.CellPainting -= DataGridViewOnCellPainting;
    }

    private static void DataGridViewOnCellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView view = sender as DataGridView;
        DataGridViewRow row = view.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

        string text = (string)cell.FormattedValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return;

        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, view.Font);
        row.Height = Math.Max(size.Height + _rowMargins, row.Height);
    }

    private static void DataGridViewOnCellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 || e.RowIndex == -1 || e.FormattedValue == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All ^ DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);

        DataGridView view = sender as DataGridView;

        string textToDisplay = TrimTextToFit(string.Format("{0}", e.FormattedValue), (int)(e.CellBounds.Width * 0.96) - 3, e.CellBounds.Height - _rowMargins, view.Font);

        bool selected = view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected;
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(selected ? e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor : e.CellStyle.ForeColor);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(textToDisplay, view.Font, brush, e.CellBounds.X + 1, e.CellBounds.Y + _rowMargins / 2);

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private static string TrimTextToFit(string text, int contentWidth, int contentHeight, Font font)
    {
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font);

        if (size.Width < contentWidth && size.Height < contentHeight)
        {
            return text;
        }

        int i = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (i < text.Length)
        {
            sb.Append(text[i++]);
            size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(sb.ToString(), font);

            if (size.Width < contentWidth) continue;

            sb.Append("...");

            while (sb.Length > 3 && size.Width >= contentWidth)
            {
                sb.Remove(sb.Length - 4, 1);
                size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(sb.ToString(), font);
            }

            while (i < text.Length && text[i] != Environment.NewLine[0])
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        string res = sb.ToString();

        if (size.Height <= contentHeight)
        {
            return res;
        }

        string[] lines = res.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        i = lines.Length;
        while (i > 1 && size.Height > contentHeight)
        {
            res = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines, 0, --i);
            size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(res, font);
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       if ((!e.Value.Equals("OK")) && e.ColumnIndex == 6)
        {
            e.CellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            //dgvObjetivos.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
            dgvObjetivos.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        }
```

http://kshitijsharma.net/2010/08/23/showing-multiline-string-in-a-datagridview-cell/